# Dúvida com trabalho de faculdade em javascript usando DOM

Tags: javascript, html5, dom

Bom dia, pessoal, tenho esse trabalho para fazer e entregar amanhã no cursinho, mas estou completamente perdido em como elaborar isso no notepad++.
Poderiam, por favor, me dar uma luz? Estou desde as 02:00 da manhã tentando e não consigo.
Agradeço desde já.

Crie um formulário em HTML com javascript com os seguintes campos:

- Valor do produto(campo de texto); quantidade(campo de texto)
- O programa deverá calcular o custo total (quantidade x valor do produto);
- O programa deverá calcular o lucro sobre cada produto (valor do produto x 65%);
- O programa deverá calcular o lucro total (lucro x quantidade);
- O programa deverá calcular os impostos sobre cada produto(valor do produto + lucro x 18,7%);
- O programa deverá calcular o imposto total (impostos * quantidade);
- O programa deverá calcular o preço de venda(valor do produto + lucro + impostos);
- Imprimir todos os cálculos dentro de um paragrafo
  (< p >)

```
<title>Trabalho</title>
<script>

function calcularImposto(){
resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
n1 = document.getElementById("n1").value;
imposto1 = parseFloat(n1)*0.22;
imposto2 = parseFloat(n1)*0.18;

resultado.innerHTML = "imposto 1" + imposto1 + "<br /> Imposto 2 " + imposto2;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <label>Número 1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="n1" id="n1" size="5" />
    <br />

    <input type="button" name="botao" id="botao" value="Calcular"  onclick="calcularSoma()" />
</form>

<p>Resultado: <span id="resultado"> 0 </span></p> 
</body>
```

Este é o código que o professor passou como exemplo para ajudar no trabalho em si. A minha duvida está em como adaptar este código para o exercícios. Pensei em fazer com algumas variaveis assim:

```
var quantidade, produto
var lucro, imposto
var totalCusto, totalImposto, totalLucro
var precoVenda

custo total = quantidade * produto
lucro = (produto / 100) * 65
imposto = ((produto + lucro) / 100) * 18,7
totalLucro = lucro * quantidade
totalImposto = imposto * quantidade
precoVenda = produto + lucro + imposto
```

Mas não sei se daria certo. Perdi algumas aulas por causa do trabalho e agora tô meio que desesperado.

Comment: Quanto ao javascript, é para usar jQuery, DOM, alguma outra API, ou o que você quiser?

Comment: Victor, devo usar o DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você tem que ler os valores do produto e da quantidade:

```js
var produto = document.getElementById("produto").value;
var quantidade = document.getElementById("quantidade").value;
```

Você precisará ter estes campos no seu HTML:

```html
<input type="text" id="produto" value="" />
<input type="text" id="quantidade" value="" />
```

No final do seu javascript, você concatena tudo em uma string bem grande e coloca ela dentro da tag `<p>` assim:

```js
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = suaString;
```

Além disso, no HTML você está usando `onclick="calcularSoma()"`, mas no javascript sua função é `calcularImposto()`.

Há mais um problema também. Você está calculando a variável imposto com um número `18,7`. Deveria ser `18.7`. É para usar ponto, e não vírgula.

---

<sup><sup>E por favor, da próxima vez coloca um título melhor na pergunta. Títulos do tipo "por favor me ajuda" tendem a irritar os membros da comunidade e deixá-los menos propensos a ajudar.</sup></sup>